# Module-registered menu paths and non-existing pages lead to non-Drupal 404

Tags: 7, routes

I'm trying to build a custom module, but I think there's something wrong with my server settings and/or Drupal install. Whenever I navigate to a non-existent site path, or even a path that is registered by a module, it goes to a generic 404 page that is not encapsulated by Drupal that looks like this:

---

Not Found

The requested URL /drupal/devel/phpinfo was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at ******** Port 80

---

Not really sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. Happy to provide more information.

Thank you!